# change status bar default color

Tags: android, colors, statusbar

When I open my application for a second it shows the status bar in blue color, even though, I declared the color to be RED.

In styles:

```
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
                <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
                <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
                <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
                <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
                <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        </style>
</resources>
```

In Colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#a20dff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>


</resources>
```

It's worth mentioning that I change the color grammatically to another color(specified by user) later.But, as in very first second it is different it looks ugly.

Comment: what is your device android OS version ?

Comment: my android version is 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with adding below line to your v21 theme:

```
 <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

**OR**

You can do it by programmatically like below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Comment: I use the second method already and it works fine but the problem is that I want my status bar to be red and when my app states working, for a second the status bar is blue. I want the status bar to be red once application started.

Comment: change `setStatusBarColor(Color.RED)` instead of `setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE)` to set red color in status bar.

Comment: I know that dude. My problem is that when I start the app for one second it has a color that is different of what I specified. Imagine the color is blue for one second then it turns to red.

Comment: okay try to put it first in your `onCreate()` method. After that do other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Implement** following method (in your Activity)

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void setStatusBarColor(int statusBarColorResId) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(statusBarColorResId));

    else Log.e("setStatusBarColor", "Operation not supported");
}
```

**Call** it as follows (e.g., from onCreate)

```
setStatusBarColor(R.color.status_bar_color);
```

Comment: I know that dude. My problem is that when I start the app for one second it has a color that is different of what I specified. Imagine the color is blue for one second then it turns to red.